# How to add DrawerLayout to my ToolBar / ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have a custom Toolbar that I've set up in my MainActivity to be the top action bar.  The question is, how do you implement a NavigationDrawer to display when the ImageView in the toolbar is clicked?

In MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main_drawer);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

My layout_main_drawer

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.XXXX" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#ccc">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_action"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,  mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    );
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Pay attention.
`android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated.

You have to use the  [android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).
This class has a constructor with the `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerString));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
                mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

After this use onDrawerOpen() & onDrawerClose() methods!
Hope this helps.

Don't forget to import:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Comment: Does the layout_main_drawer add a DrawerLayout in there?

Comment: You can use <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

in your xml file

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AtharvaPuranik you are using the deprecated ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes I already made changes to that in my code!